# Matlab fopen, is it possible to have a numeric file name?

Tags: matlab, fopen

I have the following code:

```
ptol = [2, 4, 8, ...];

a = ptol(1)

fid = fopen( a,'r');
```

I need to open a file determined by which number is called from `ptol`, i.e. if `ptol(1)` = 2, then `fopen` should open file 2.

Currently I get the error "invalid filename". How do I fix this?

The following code is what I need to use to "load" the data in the files I'm struggling to open in to a matrix.

```
fileName = strcat(num2str(a),'.ext');
file = fopen(fileName,'r');

count = 1;

lines2skip = 4;

mat = zeros(29,872);

while ~feof(file)
    if count <= lines2skip
        count = count+1;
        [~] = fgets(file); % throw away unwanted line
        continue;
    else
        line = strtrim(fgets(file));
        mat = [mat ;cell2mat(textscan(line, '%f')).'];
        count = count +1;
    end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by file 2? What is the actual file name? Is it just `2.txt` ??

Comment: Yes, the actual name is 2.txt

Comment: Then, as Eleanore has suggested, you need convert `a` from double tp string and add the correct file extension. Eleanore's answer is correct. You other error is because you are not passing the correct file id to `feof`. It should be `while ~feof(fid)`. `file` isn't defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: Isn't file defined on the second line?

Comment: Yes, it is, you're right. I was looking at the first bit of code in your question, where you were using `fid` for the file ID, not `file`.  As Eleanore mentioned, you need to replace `'.ext'` by the correct file extension, which in your case is `'.txt'`. Check the value returned by `file`. If it's -1, then there's an error somewhere: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html

Answer (score 4):

`a` is a number, I guess.

Thus, you need to specify a **string** which corresponds to the file name.
Does the file have any extension? `num2str` and `strcat` should do the magic.

The code:

```
fileName = strcat(num2str(a),'.ext');
fid = fopen(fileName,'r');
```

Notice that `.ext` has to be replace with the **actual** extension. If you are using `.txt` files, then replace with `.txt`.

Also, check for the position of the file (you need to specify the exact path).

Comment: Mixed results. I get the error: "Error using feof
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

Error in Untitled4 (line 20)
while ~feof(file)"

I'll edit my post above with all my code.

Comment: According to your code, you are requiring to open the file '2.ext', while you said in your comments that your file name is '2.txt'. Obviously, '.ext' needs to be replaced with your actual extension.

Comment: It is really easy to see whether you are doing something wrong with the `fopen` command: if you get `fid=-1` then you are not reading correctly the file.